# Open id and facebook implementation in php?

Tags: php, facebook, openid, implementation

I am using Open ID on my website using [Dope Openid](http://stevelove.org/projects/dope-openid/) library but I would like to add facebook as an open id provider to the list since facebook also supports OpenID...Can anyone help me out with an explanation or link me to a tutorial (staga.net is using it flawlessly on their site)
*if someone can also explain to me how Staga is using buttons instead of a text box(even SO uses a text box) to have an open ID support...Thanks

Comment: The search button is your friend

Comment: I have searched stack overflow and that's where i found out  about dope open id...

Answer (score 1):

check out [rpxnow](https://rpxnow.com/)

I'm not sure if I'm mistaking, but I don't believe facebook as of yet offers itself as an openId provider, but rather a consumer. That is you can log on to facebook using your gmail account, but you can't log on to stackoverflow by using your facebook account.

Last time I checked, I found facebook's implementation of an openId sign on to miss the point. To logon to the service using OpenID, go to Account Settings > Linked Accounts, pick an OpenID provider. However, facebook requires that your provider remembers that setting. If you don't have google set to remember facebook as an OpenID site, you won't be able to log on. Which to me is a bit ridiculous, but oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is not an OpenID provider. If you want people to authenticate via Facebook, you'll need to implement their Facebook Connect API.

http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php