# PHP - Simple way to allow login using Facebook, Google and Twitter

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a service/script that allow me to add login to Facebook, twitter, google... in one solution: i have tried Hibridauth but it doesn't work at least for me, i don't find tutorial for Facebook and openid and i don't want to use paid service or free but limited ones.

Do you know something good?

Comment: Are you on any sort of Framework? Elliot Haughin has some awesome CodeIgniter libraries @ http://www.haughin.com/

Comment: what's wrong with HybridAuth?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [Zend_Oauth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check this Links you may find a solution

[PHP OpenID Library that allows facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237262/php-openid-library-that-allows-facebook-openid-twitter-etc)

[Getting Started with OpenID and PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581)

[Open id and facebook implementation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580706/open-id-and-facebook-implementation-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but i have read this in a comment on a blog The comment is 
"Check out NinjAuth which is currently a Fuel package. You can find the repo here https://github.com/philsturgeon/fuel-ninjauth and description here http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/09/ninjauth-social-integration-php"

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi sorry yes its for phpfuel but i would leave this answer here may be its helpful to some one.