# Handling logins from multiple third-party APIs

Tags: php, api, authentication, accounts

I need to implement an accounts system that lets users login via the Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn APIs. I'm looking for the most simplest and most efficient way to do this on the backend, using MySQL and PHP. Here's what I have in mind as a starting point:

First, I would create two database schemas.

- users (id, name, password hash)
- thirdPartyLogins (userId,
  serviceName, token)

Then, I would run the following query to fetch a user's record using the token provided by a third-party API.

```
SELECT * FROM users, thirdPartyLogins
WHERE serviceName = $serviceName 
AND token = $token
AND thirdPartyLogins.userID = users.id
LIMIT 1
```

Is this an efficient way to handle the third-party logins? Would you suggest any tweaks (or existing frameworks) for expediting development of such an accounts system?

Thanks in advance for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of developing your own system, which you will have to develop and maintain, you should just use an existing library :

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

This SO question is also talking about it:
[PHP - Simple way to allow login using Facebook, Google and Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797481/php-simple-way-to-allow-login-using-facebook-google-and-twitter)

Hope this helps!

[edit]
Actually this seems like a pretty recent and good resource : 
http://www.9lessons.info/2013/03/oauth-login-for-linkedin-facebook.html